# Unable to install Xamarin for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, installation

I have VS2013, VS2015, JDK and Android SDK installed. Now I'm trying to install Xamarin for VS, but the installation fails near the end and prompts me to download the independent components separately with links to the separate downloads.  I can't do that either because when I do try, an error pops up saying the file doesn't have a valid signature.

I have the log file of the error but I can't attach it.

Comment: Could you post a link to the [installer logs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/#Xamarin_Universal_installer) and error message?

Comment: That usually indicates your network connection is not reliable or blocked with limited access. That's a problem you should ping your network administrator.

Comment: To find the detail error information of this failed installation, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here. You can have a try with use another different browser to download it, if you used the IE, you can go to Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Security and check the “Allow software to run or install even if the signature is invalid” and apply, then reopen IE to check this issue.

Comment: I restarted my system and tried reinstalling several times, each time the installation size became smaller and smaller until it installed fully.

Comment: @SumaiyaChotani, so did you get the same issue again? If so, you need to share the logs like I mentioned before.